# Update field using Trigger

Tags: visualforce, trigger

I want to update the object's field using trigger

```
trigger load_Project_People_junc_obj_1 on People__c (after insert, after update) 
{
    for (People__c objPeople : Trigger.new) 
    {
        List <Project_People__c> lstProjectPeople = new List<Project_People__c>();
        if (objPeople.Primary_Project_Id__c == null && objPeople.Project_Start_Date__c != null)                
        {
            Date dt=Date.today()
            objPeople.Project_Start_Date__c = date.today();
            update(objPeople);
        }
    }        
}
```

Issue:- Field not getting upated to todays date. I want the field to get updated to todays date if `Primary_Project_Id__c` is `null`.

Comment: is if block being executed?...is that If condition correct?

Comment: Yes, Block gets executed without any error. But field does not get updated :(

Comment: Date dt=Date.today();
 objPeople.Project_Start_Date__c = date.today();............this line can be written as objPeople.Project_Start_Date__c = Date.today();...no need to create class instance to access only static method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your firing on after insert and after update. You shouldn't be updating the record that the trigger is firing on in these events. Change your code to:

- Fire on Before Update and Before Insert
- Remove the update line.

This should work:

```
trigger load_Project_People_junc_obj_1 on People__c (before insert, before update) 
{
    for (People__c objPeople : Trigger.new) 
    {
        if (objPeople.Primary_Project_Id__c == null && objPeople.Project_Start_Date__c != null)                
        {
            objPeople.Project_Start_Date__c = date.today();
        }
    }        
}
```

Have a look at [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2033/how-should-i-determine-whether-to-use-before-or-after-when-writing-a-trigger) which explains when to use the Before event and when to use the after event. In this case, because you are modifying a record that is causing the trigger to fire you should be using the before event.

Comment: Can you add an explanation of why this works better using BEFORE triggers?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you're either specifying a start date in `Project_Start_Date__c`, or it has a default value (check the field config).

Additionally, you shouldn't call `update` inside the loop, it's best practice to fill a list and insert all the new records in one go to help avoid hitting governor limits. That said, if you change this to a `before insert` and `before update` trigger you don't even need to make an update call since you're updating the value before the record even hits the database. This also removes the need to use extra code to prevent triggers from cascading: if you update a record after insert, it'll fire the update trigger again, which would fire the update trigger again which would.... you get the picture.

```
trigger load_Project_People_junc_obj_1 on People__c (before insert, before update) 
{
    for (People__c objPeople : Trigger.new) 
    {
        if (objPeople.Primary_Project_Id__c == null && objPeople.Project_Start_Date__c != null)                
        {
            objPeople.Project_Start_Date__c = date.today();
        }
    }
}
```

Last but not least, could you just use a formula field to achieve the same effect? Might be the more maintainable solution.