# Trigger for Converting Amount(Currency/Number) to Words

Tags: apex, trigger, currency, convert, words

Has anyone else come up with a solution by Trigger for this?  I have been trying to figure this out for a few weeks now but to no avail.

```
for e.g Amount -  200$

        Amount in words - Two hundred Dollar only.
```

I found apex class from this website http://salesforcewithkiran.blogspot.in/2013/05/number-to-words-in-apex.html

that works fine for apex class but not for apex trigger.

and I found another site [check this here](https://sites.google.com/a/forcegenie.com/kb/home/numberstowords/7-ways-to-integrate-with-your-salesforce-org/continouos-conversion-from-number-currency-to-text-using-a-trigger) with trigger program to convert but they calling a NumbersToWords apex class but there is no code for that class.

**Need a Trigger to convert numbers/currency to words**

Anyone have idea about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you reference in your question works on a single number that must be a positive `Long` value. So in your trigger you will have to loop over what can be the many (bulk) values passed to the trigger via the `Trigger.new` list of the [trigger context](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm), [convert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm#apex_System_Decimal_longValue) the value to a `Long` and then assign the resulting `String`. Because it is a [before trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2033/how-should-i-determine-whether-to-use-before-or-after-when-writing-a-trigger), the result will automatically be saved to the database.

You don't name the object and fields, but if it were a couple of custom fields on `Contact`, the code would look something like this:

```
trigger MyTrigger on Contact (before insert, before update) {
    for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
        if (c.Number__c != null && c.Number__c >= 0) {
            Long n = c.Number__c.longValue();
            c.Text__c = NumberToWord.english_number(n);
        } else {
            c.Text__c = null;
        }
    }
}
```

(You will also have to copy and add the NumberToWord class to your org before you create the trigger.)